A small issue about review queue
When a post is somebody's first answer and at the same time happens to be a late answer, this will appear in both First Answer and Late Answer review queue. So you will have to click twice only to find it's the same post. Not a big issue. But it would be better if logic could be added to check if posts in different queues are actually the same ones.
Not sure if it's a LE specific issue, though.

The same post can appear in different review queues for different reasons.
Late Answers is for any answers from low-rep (<50?) users that are posted long (6 months?) after the question they were posted on. First Answers is for each new user's very first post on the site. So it's quite possible for an answer to be eligible for either one of these review queues but not the other: for instance, a new user's second answer, or their first answer but it was posted on a new question.
There's no mechanism to stop a post from appearing in multiple review queues, which in most cases is good: the kind of scrutiny needed in the Low Quality Posts review queue, for instance, might be different from either of the above. I do get your point that it's redundant to have the same post in both FA and LA review queues, but there's arguably a slight difference between the purposes of those queues (one is for helping to guide brand-new users, while the other is for checking that nothing is wrong with an old but recently-bumped post). More importantly, there's no particular downside to having the same post appearing in both review queues. Best case scenario, two different people review it, which means twice as many eyes on it and more likelihood of any issue being noticed. Worst case scenario, a very small waste of time.
Finally, this is indeed not specific to Literature - the mechanisms for review queues are the same on (almost) all SE sites. More info can be found at this FAQ on main meta: What are the review queues, and how do they work?
